# addition of 2x2 matrices with operator overloading

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-keyword

I have the following code.
The code works fine without the operator + part.
It gives me

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘final[i][j] = (((matrix*)this)->matrix::mat[i][j] + matr->matrix::mat[i][j])’

and

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << final[i][j]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


class matrix {

private :

int i,j;
double mat[2][2];


public :
matrix () {
}

void getdata();
double determinant();
matrix operator + (matrix &);

};

//getdata
void matrix :: getdata() {
cout <<"Please provide a 2x2 matrix :"<<endl;

    for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
cout <<"Give the elements of the matrix : "<<endl;
cin >> mat[i][j];
        }
        }
}

//compute determinant
double matrix :: determinant () {

double det;

det = mat[0][0]*mat[1][1] -mat[0][1]*mat[1][0];


cout <<"The determinant of the matrix is :"<<det<<endl;


}

//compute addition
matrix matrix ::operator +(matrix &matr) {
matrix final[2][2];
for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
final[i][j]=mat[i][j]+matr.mat[i][j];
    }
}
cout <<"The addition of the two matrices is :"<<endl;

for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
cout << final[i][j];
    }
cout <<endl;
}

}


int  main()
{
   matrix pinakas1,pinakas2;
   pinakas1.getdata();
   pinakas2.getdata();
   pinakas1.determinant();
   pinakas2.determinant();
   pinakas1+pinakas2;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember a return value if a function is non-void. The method `double matrix :: determinant ()` should return a value.

Comment: Remember also that having `operator+()` doesn't automatically give you `operator+=()`, and that can be an annoyance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `matrix final[2][2];` declares a 2-d array of matrices, so `final[i][j]` is of type `matrix &` and the relevant operators aren't defined. You must have meant `double final[2][2];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `operator+` as,

```
matrix matrix ::operator +(const matrix &matr) 
{
    matrix final;
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++) 
    {
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++) 
        {
            final.mat[i][j]=mat[i][j]+matr.mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return final;
}
```

Use `final.mat` to access the actual data member. Also `matrix final[2][2]` declares two dimensional array of type `matrix`. It doesn't do what you intend it to do!

Comment: Actually, writing `operator+=` and defining `operator+` in terms of that is probably the way to go.

Comment: Hello,it didn't work like that.I had to do "double final[2][2]" and not matrix final;

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a << operator for your matrix.

'final' is defined as a 2x2 array f 'matrix'  (`matrix final[2][2];`)

Therefore `cout << final[i][j];` references a matrix object.